# Is it possible to compute residual variances of Laplacian Eigenmaps, Diffusion Map and t-SNE to have a scree plots as in PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, variance, data-visualization, dimensionality-reduction, manifold-learning

I will like to do comparative analysis of `PCA` vs. `Laplacian Eigenmaps`, `Diffusion Map`, and `t-SNE`. For this, I can create **scree plot** (with residual variance) for PCA and check the **elbow of the curve**.

Is it possible to do the same for Laplacian Eigenmap, Diffusion Map, and t-SNE? If yes, what is the mathematical formulation for that? Is it the same as for PCA?

I know it is not possible for `LLE` as here residual variance does not make any sense.

Is there any MATLAB/Python code available for it?